# Cannot post a question

Tags: bug, status-completed, browser-support

So I've posted a few questions before... Including a couple in the past week on this PC with this browser. Today I can't. When I (re)load the page I get the following errors.  Literally nothing happens when I click "Review your question" - No console errors or anything visible.  I have disabled uBlock Origin. The only other extensions running are Dark Reader and BitWarden.  Microsoft Edge Version 94.0.992.50 (Official build) (64-bit)

[image]

Comment: Obviously, this posted fine. First try.

Comment: After posting this, I opened a new tab, went to stackoverflow home page, clicked "Ask Question" and got the same results.

Comment: Possibly related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/370955/332043

Comment: I opened a new inPrivate window and logged in. Same results. Also, surprisingly, it loaded my draft.  I also attempted to remove all tags and post, still nothing, not even an error about no tags.

Comment: It's not just SO, it's on multiple sites. And it's going to happen as long as you've got the same JS and the HTML is missing this "webpack-public-path" element. :(  The meta sites might be using a different javascript for questions.

Comment: Where are you in the world, roughly? It might be a stale cache at Fastly.

Comment: I am in Austin.

Comment: Thanks for reporting this! It was caused by the same bug as https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370955/review-queues-not-working-because-of-javascript-error, I've posted a lengthy summary of the issue over there

Comment: Curious, why close as "off topic"? Isn't there a "resolved" function or similar?

Comment: "The problem described here can no longer be reproduced. **Changes to the system or to the circumstances affecting the asker have rendered it obsolete**. If you encounter a similar problem, please post a new question."

Comment: That *is* the "resolved" function, along with the [[meta-tag:status-completed]] tag. I have no idea why people voted to reopen this.